# How to include input field in vscode Activity Bar (Sidebar)

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am trying to create a vscode extension. I go through the docs for creating the [activitybar](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/contribution-points#contributes.viewsContainers), but I could not find any docs related to add input/search field inside the activity bar.

I saw the inbuild extension like extension manager, version control systems, etc are having the search bar inside the `activiyBar`.

[image]

Comment: That is the SideBar.  The ActivityBar is on the far left where the icons are.

Comment: Yeah, how to include input in viewContainer?